# Possible solution against Emacs+Matplotlib freeze

Tags: matplotlib, emacs

I have struggled for days to plot graphs using Emacs and matplotlib library on Windows10.
I tested several proposals taken here and there but with no success.
Sometimes I had no graph and the freeze of Python buffer, sometimes I got a graph but also the freeze.

Here is a solution that works for me. Maybe it can be help (maybe not).

Install ipython (pip install ipython)
Install matplotlib (pip install matplotlib)

Add these lines to init.el

```
(when (executable-find "ipython")
  (setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython"))
```

Run Emacs and ipython (M-x run-python)
Load matplotlib (import matplolib)
Verify the use of TkAgg backend (matplotlib.get_backend()). Qt doesn't work for me.
If not, add this line to matplotlibrc
backend : TkAgg

The following script should now work with no freeze (at least, this is the case for me)

```
matplotlib.get_backend()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ioff()
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()
print("Test")
```

Comment: What's the question? This looks like an answer to a question that hasn't been posted.